# MySql: What is the structure for "IF" formula? Please give example

Tags: mysql, if-statement, formula, navicat

I try to use formula "IF" in view but dont know what the structure.

Basically I try to divide two group of number.

0,1,2,3,4 after "IF" = 0 and 5,6,7,8,9 after "IF" = 1.

Here is an example of my database:

Row 1 /
Column A = 8
column B = 1
column C = 2
Column D = 5
Column E = 7
Column F = 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFs in mysql is CASE: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html